# what is the meaning of hashable in dict

Tags: python-3.x

why I cannot write this `{names: heroes}` inside the dictionary .when I did this
`{{names: heroes} for names, heroes in zip(names, heroes)}` an error occurred which is a type error saying `unhashable dict`. What does that mean?

```
nums={{names:heroes} for names, heroes in zip(names,heroes)}
print(nums)
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/ahmod/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37-32/mim.py", line 7, in <module>
    nums={{names:heroes} for names, heroes in zip(names,heroes)}
  File "C:/Users/ahmod/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37-32/mim.py", line 7, in <setcomp>
    nums={{names:heroes} for names, heroes in zip(names,heroes)}
TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'
```

Comment: `nums={name:hero for name, hero in zip(names,heroes)}`

Answer (score 1):

```
{{names: heroes} for names, heroes in zip(names, heroes)}
```

This is a set comprehension -because you are using the `{}` curly braces. In a `set`, each element must be hashable. you are setting each elements in the set to `{names: heroes}` - which is a `dict`. So you are trying to make a `set` of `dict`.

But unfortunately, in python, `dict` is not hashable - since it's a mutable type.

So you can't do that.

Instead you can try to create a dictionary directly:

```
{name: heroe for name, heroe in zip(names, heroes)}
```

By just removing the extra curly braces.